# Swipe a single cell in ListView to a new View fullscreen - React Native

Tags: javascript, mobile, view, react-native, swipe

I have a list view and I want when the user swipe left to each cell, there will be a swipe effect that open another big view, just like in Snapchat, when we are at the list of my contacts, I can swipe left to enter the chat view with that particular contact.

How can I achieve that with React Native? Are there any libraries that allow me to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking for, but potentially a Drawer could provide what you're looking for. There are a few react-native implementations, I've used this one: https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer

Comment: Thanks! Actually I can tweak around that library and achieve what I'm looking for!